# Converting from one date format to another using DB Browser for SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am looking to convert one date format to another using SQL. I am using DB Browser for SQLite and the dates are stored in a column of type 'TEXT'.

Here are 2 examples of the current format:

4/17/2017 9:09:09 AM

10/4/2017 10:21:13 PM

Note that in the current format for the day, month and hour they currently do not pad with a leading '0' if only a single digit. Also they are putting the month first, then the day, then the year.
These 2 examples should be converted to the YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS (24 hour) format:

i.e.

4/17/2017 9:09:09 AM -> 2017-04-17 09:09:09

10/4/2017 10:21:13 PM -> 2017-10-04 22:21:13

etc.

If anyone could provide me with a SQL query that can convert all values in a column like the first format into the second format that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You could probably pull it off with some obscene chain of `instr()` and `substr()` commands, but it would almost certainly be quicker and less painful to use python or something for this.

Comment: See [Reformat dates in column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40984650/11654), but the time fields result in 32 possible combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I don't know much about python so had to go with the 'obscene chain of instr() and substr() commands'. It's a mess, but it seems to work now.

`instr(DATE,'/')` used to find the position of the first '/'

`length (rtrim(DATE, 'PMA0123456789: '))` used to find the position of the second '/'

`instr(DATE, ':')` used to find the position of the first ':'

Well below is the mess I created :D

```
UPDATE testtable
SET DATE = 
substr (DATE, length (rtrim(DATE, 'PMA0123456789: '))+1,4) || '-' ||
CASE instr(DATE, '/')
    WHEN 2 THEN
        '0' 
    ELSE ''
END 
|| substr (DATE,1,instr(DATE,'/')-1) || '-' ||
CASE (length (rtrim(DATE, 'PMA0123456789: '))) - instr(DATE,'/')
    WHEN 2 THEN
        '0' 
    ELSE '' 
END 
|| substr (DATE,instr(DATE,'/')+1, length (rtrim(DATE, 'PMA0123456789: ')) - instr(DATE,'/')-1)
|| ' ' || 
CASE substr(DATE,length(DATE)-1,2)
    WHEN 'AM' THEN
        CASE substr(DATE, instr(DATE, ':')-2,2)
            WHEN '12' then
                '00'
            ELSE
                CASE substr(DATE, instr(DATE, ':')-2, 1)
                    WHEN ' ' THEN 
                        '0'
                    ELSE
                        substr(DATE, instr(DATE, ':')-2,1)  
                END
                || substr(DATE, instr(DATE, ':')-1,1) 
        END
    WHEN 'PM' THEN
        CASE substr(DATE, instr(DATE, ':')-2,2) 
            WHEN '12' THEN
                substr(DATE, instr(DATE, ':')-2,2) 
            ELSE
                CAST (substr(DATE,instr(DATE, ':')-2,2) AS INT) + 12 
        END
    ELSE
        'error'
END 
|| ':' || substr(DATE,instr(DATE, ':')+1,5);
```